# What is a good way to model fluid stream contours around airfoils?

Tags: plotting, physics, parametric-functions

I am an undergraduate student and am doing a project on conformal mapping for my complex analysis class. I have had one heck of a time trying to plot stream function contours to model fluid flow in *Mathematica* and I am not strong enough in MATLAB to consider switching.

I have a method already but it is somewhat cumbersome and was hoping someone might have a better method. I am particularly interested in using numerical methods where I can perhaps transform and plot independent points instead of having mathematica deal with entire expressions. Please let me know if I am approaching any common pitfalls as well.

```
wEllipse[z_, b_] := z + (b)^2/z;
wEllipseParametricTry[t_, n_] := 
   1/2 (n/(v0*Sin[t]) + Sqrt[(n/(v0*Sin[t]))^2 +
   4*rOd^2])*Exp[I*t] +(1.5*rOd)^2/(1/2 (n/(v0*Sin[t]) + 
   Sqrt[(n/(v0*Sin[t]))^2 + 4*rOd^2])*Exp[I*t]);

pTestEllipse = 
  ParametricPlot[
    {Re[wEllipse[rOd*Exp[I*t], 1.5 rOd]],
     Im[wEllipse[rOd*Exp[I*t], 1.5 rOd]]}, 
  {t, 0, 2 π}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Ellipse"]

Show[
  Table[
    ParametricPlot[
      {Re[wEllipseParametricTry[t, n]], 
       Im[wEllipseParametricTry[t, n]]}, 
      {t, 0.001, 0.999 π},
      PlotLabel -> "Ellipse Stream Line One", 
      PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-10, 10}}, 
      PlotStyle -> Red], 
    {n, -3, 0, 0.25}],
  Table[
    ParametricPlot[
      {Re[wEllipseParametricTry[t, n]], 
       Im[wEllipseParametricTry[t, n]]}, 
      {t, -0.999 π, 0.001}, 
      PlotLabel -> "Ellipse Stream Line One", 
      PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-10, 10}}, 
      PlotStyle -> Red], 
    {n, 0, 3, 0.25}], 
  pTestEllipse]
```

#### Notes

- The range of `t` is important. See 
  (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582652/joukowski-conformal-\
  mapping) for details.
- β < rOd

[image]

Comment: It would really help if you could post your code as text, properly formatted, so people can copy and paste it into Mathematica to play with it. Here are some formatting pointers: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951

Comment: Have you seen [`StreamPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html)?

Comment: This question is too broad at the moment. Also,  please post any code also as code, not only as image.

Comment: This question puts too much of a burden on those who might be able to answer it. Unless you supply self-contained working code, properly formatted and free from irrelevancies, and which can be copied from your post and pasted into a Mathematica notebook, it is not likely to be answered.

Comment: Thank you all for the input. I will edit my post as soon as possible for ease of use.

Comment: You post still contains undefined free variables `v0` and `rOd`. Please give a definition for them.

Comment: I don't get your question. You want to make a nice drawing of some imagined flow lines or put real physics to it? In the former case I don't see what a "good way" is, and in the latter you would need to solve navier-stokes equations for your geometry. In the code you show you are using a very loose definition of model btw. However I have the impression your question is not so much about how to solve the physics but how to plot lines.